# interpretation of List<NeighboursCellInfo> informations

Tags: android, telephonymanager, cellinfo

i developed a mini application that get back the neighbours cells informations, i used telephonymanager class.

I got the information bellow, my problem is that i cant interpret its :

```
    07-03 10:40:25.044  11455-11455/com.example.transatel.android511 I/System.out﹕ [[1a9@-77], [b5@-79], [b5@-80], [1a9@-80], [35@-79]]

    07-03 10:54:36.565  11455-11455/com.example.transatel.android511 I/System.out﹕ [[b5@-76], [35@-78], [142@-86], [b5@-81]]
```

can someone help me to interpret this information, if the list is in hex or ascii or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/telephony/NeighboringCellInfo.java#NeighboringCellInfo.toString%28%29) of toString method the first part (before "@") is either Primary Scrambling Code or LAC and cell id, while the second part is signal strength. I would assume that in your case the first part is primary scrambling code, since those numbers are 9-bit